# Application crahses if runs under special user

Tags: c#, windows, process

I want to start a third party application ( https://www.careoline.de/files/mcCrypt/mcCrypt3.zip) under a special user, for security reasons.

If I do so, the application doesn't work correctly (Return code is not equal 'ok').
Under my user everything is running well.

I used the Sysinternals Process Monitor and filters for all `ACCESS DENIED` Events. There are a lot Events regarding `HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache`.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious explanation here is ...

> The application appears to be broken or requires permissions the
>   special user does not have.